# How do you specify variables when rending a formattable table in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, formattable

I'm trying to create and render an interactive formattable table in a shiny app.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
tcharts <- data.frame(pgm = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
        horse = c("Cigar", "Funny Cide", "Animal Kingdom", "Blame", "Zenyatta", "New Years Day", "Northern Dancer", "Beautiful Pleasure"),
        groundloss = c(55,70,85,42,90,45,53,50),
        distanceRun = c(5050,5070,5085,5045,5090,5045,5053,5050),
        ttl = c(50,70,85,42,90,45,53,50),
        fps = c(52.3,51.8,51.9,52.0,53.6,52.9,53.7,53.1),
        finishTime = c(52.3,51.8,51.9,52.0,53.6,52.9,53.7,53.1),
        finish = c(4,7,1,2,5,6,3,8),
        BL = c(0,1,2,6,2,9,6,8),
        rnum = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
        sixteenth = c(330,330,330,330,330,330,330)
        )
```

#### Working version

This version of the code, when list() is empty (use all variables in dataframe) produces a table as expected.

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)



inputPanel(
      selectInput("rnum", label = "Race Number:",
                  choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), selected = 1),

      sliderInput("poc", label = "Point of Call:",
                  min = 330, max = 5280, value = 330, step = 330)
    )


    cdat <- reactive({
        tcharts %>% filter(rnum %in% input$rnum) %>%
        filter(Sixteenth %in% input$poc)
    })

    renderFormattable({
      formattable(cdat(),list(

      ))

    })
```

#### Error Version:

With this version, I get an ERROR: object pgm not found

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)

        inputPanel(
      selectInput("rnum", label = "Race Number:",
                  choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), selected = 1),

      sliderInput("poc", label = "Point of Call:",
                  min = 330, max = 5280, value = 330, step = 330)
    )


    cdat <- reactive({
        tcharts %>% filter(rnum %in% input$rnum) %>%
        filter(Sixteenth %in% input$poc)
    })

    renderFormattable({
      formattable(cdat(),list(
      pgm,
      Horse
      ))

    })
```

The error message leads me to believe I'm not specifying the variable correctly, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'v looked at several formattable / shiny SO questions and responses, but have not come up with the correct sytax.

Comment: is `pgm` a variable in `tcharts`? can you share example data from `tcharts` to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Ben the sample df is a subset of tcharts.

Comment: thanks --- what `formatter` do you want to use? for example, instead of including `pgm` by itself in `list` try `pgm = color_bar("pink")` - i just tried this out and it works in a shiny example...

Comment: @ Ben thank you. color_bar("pink") works for me. I tested that vary formater but got the pgm not found.

Comment: @Ben was I specifying the variables incorrectly.

Comment: my past experience using `formattable` is to assign formatters to variables in a list as in these [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html). without any formatters applied, it just renders the table as an html table. if you create a custom `formatter` you can apply to a variable in your list.